# Session.Clear() and Redirecting Issue

Tags: c#, session, asp.net-mvc-5

I am using `Predicate Builder` to allow the user to filter through the database table and search for specific records that they need/want in my application.

Now, when combining `paging` and `Predicate Builder` I had to store the user's search in a `Session` so that when they search for specific record(s) and the search returned more record(s) than what 1 page can hold.. then they will be able to go to page 2 and still have the records that match their query.

Now, in order for them to search for other records they are going to have to clear that session and start a new one... so on my *Index* page where the user is able to search I have created a button that they can click to clear their session:

```
<input type="button" class="btn btn-primary top-margin" value="Clear Search" onclick="location.href='@Url.Action("ClearSearch", "DailySummaries", new { area = "" })'" />
```

In my controller this is simple:

```
public ActionResult ClearSearch()
{
    Session.Clear();
    return RedirectToAction("allDailySummaries");
}
```

But here is the issue.. when the user clicks that button, it returns them to the initial page.  How do I clear their session without redirecting them back to the initial page?

To better explain.. imagine that I searched for All Daily Summaries between 4/01/2016 and 04/12/2016.  Now I am done with that search, and I want to search for something else... I hit the 'Clear Search' button but all I want it to do is clear the session and stay on the page that it is currently on.. not clear the session and then redirect me back to the initial page.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to say without knowing a few more implementation details. Personally, when I have had to solve problems like this, I tend to revert to our good friend javascript.

Essentially, the process I would follow is:

1. Use javascript to create a post request to the server to clear that users session (Note, I use post rather than get, as the action has a consequence on the server)
2. I ask the grid to reload the first page by either requesting the javascript grid plugin I am using to reload, or if I am doing manual paging, clicking the first button programmatically.

You should consider graceful degradation for non-javascript users too, in which cases the re-direct is probably the correct method.